# MySql query works but syntax error in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

This query in mySql gives me the result I want:

```
SELECT reportcolumn.name 
FROM report 
LEFT Join reportcolumn 
ON report.id=reportcolumn.reportid 
WHERE report.title = "Report"
```

However, when I try to write it as DQL, I get a syntax error.

```
        $report = "Reportname";
        $statement = 'SELECT c.name';
        $statement .= ' FROM AcmeDataBundle:Report r';
        $statement .= ' LEFT JOIN AcmeDataBundle:Reportcolumn c';
        $statement .= ' ON r.id=c.reportid';
        $statement .= ' WHERE r.title = :title';
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery($statement)
        ->setParameters(array(
            'title'=> $report,
            ));
        $data = $query->getArrayResult();
```

How should I be handling the "ON" part of the statement. The relationship is defined, but if I leave that part of the statement out, I get obviously wrong results.

Thanks,
Manisha

Comment: Let me consult my crystal ball to determine the exact text of this mysterious *"syntax error"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research in other questions, it appears that the problem is that you can't use "ON" in dql. Instead, "WITH" is the appropriate command. And changing the query to this, returned the correct set of column names (the many table) related to the selected report.

```
                $report = "Reportname";
        $statement = 'SELECT c.name';
        $statement .= ' FROM AcmeDataBundle:Reportcolumn c'; //select from the many table
        $statement .= ' LEFT JOIN AcmeDataBundle:Report r';
        $statement .= ' WITH r.id=c.reportid'; //use WITH not ON
        $statement .= ' WHERE r.title = :title';
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery($statement)
        ->setParameters(array(
            'title'=> $report,
            ));
        $data = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AcmeDataBundle:Report
AcmeDataBundle:Reportcolumn
```

should be

```
AcmeDataBundle.Report
AcmeDataBundle.Reportcolumn
```

Unless these are the real table names in which case you need to quote the table names with backquotes.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, but that didn't work. The new error is [Semantical Error] line 0, col 87 near 'c': Error: Class Acme\DataBundle\Entity\Report has no association named reportcolumn. I used generate entities to create the classes, but I think I need to create a one to many association in the Report class, whereas only a join in reportcolumn was created when running the command.